# Understanding “inferred type arguments do not conform to type parameter bounds” errors in Scala

Tags: scala, types, type-parameter

I fail to understand why I am getting an “inferred type arguments do not conform to type parameter bounds”.
First, I defined a trait called CS which may be implemented by several classes (e.g., CS01 and CS02):

```
trait CS[+T <: CS[T]] {
  this: T =>
  def add: T
  def remove: T
}

class CS01 extends CS[CS01] {
  def add: CS01 = new CS01
  def remove: CS01 = new CS01
}

class CS02 extends CS[CS02] {
  def add: CS02 = new CS02
  def remove: CS02 = new CS02
}
```

The idea is to keep the implemented type when calling `add` or `remove` on CS01 and CS02.
Secondly, I would like to define operations that may be executed on every classes compliant with trait CS. Then, I defined a trait called `Exec`(with two very simple examples of classes `Exec01` and `Exec02` mixin the `Exec` traits):

```
trait Exec {
  def exec[U <: CS[U]](x: U): U
}

class Exec01 extends Exec {
  def exec[U <: CS[U]](x: U): U = x.add
}

class Exec02 extends Exec {
  def exec[U <: CS[U]](x: U): U = x.remove
}
```

Once again, I need to keep the implemented type of the class that mixes the `CS` trait. That is why exec is parametrized with `[U <: CS[U]]`.

Finally, I want any `CS` enabling operations on it to mixin the trait `Executable` which makes it possible to execute an operation that follows trait `Exec`:

```
trait Executable[T <: CS[T]] {
  this: T =>
  def execute(e: Exec): T = e.exec(this)
}
```

However, I get the following error when I am trying to compile:

```
error: inferred type arguments [this.Executable[T] with T] do not conform to method exec's type parameter bounds [U <: this.CS[U]]
  def execute(e: Exec): T = e.exec(this)
                              ^
```

I don't quite understand because any classes that mix `Executable` must be of type `T` with the constraint of mixin the CS trait due to the bound in `trait Executable[T <: CS[T]]`. So, why `this` does not conform to the type parameter bound `U <: CS[U]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works if you specify the type parameter to exec explicitly:

```
def execute(e: Exec): T = e.exec[T](this)
```

Seems to be a limitation in the type inference.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer: not a scala guru here, I'm learning it as I'm writing this*.

First, let's simplify the example.

```
scala> trait Moo[+X <: Moo[X]] 
defined trait Moo

scala> class Foo extends Moo[Foo]
defined class Foo

scala> def foobar[U <: Moo[U]](x: U) = x
foobar: [U <: Moo[U]](x: U)U

scala> foobar(new Foo)
res0: Foo = Foo@191275b

scala> class Bar extends Foo
defined class Bar

scala> foobar(new Bar)
<console>:12: error: inferred type arguments [Bar] do not conform to method 
foobar's type parameter bounds [U <: Moo[U]]
              foobar(new Bar)
              ^

scala>
```

`foobar` accepts a `Foo` argument but rejects a `Bar` which only extends `Foo`. Why? `foobar` is a generic, paramaterized by the type of its argument. It imposes a bound on *that* type. The type inferencer will not check each and every ancestor of the argument type, hoping to find one that satisfies the bound.

So how to impose a bound on an ancestor type? One method is with existential types.

```
scala> def foobar[V <: Moo[U] forSome {type U}](x: V) = x
foobar: [U <: Moo[_], V <: U](x: V)V

scala> foobar(new Foo)
res3: Foo = Foo@1154718

scala> foobar(new Bar)
res4: Bar = Bar@5a7ff7

scala>
```

Comment: Well, this is not exactly my question. However, your point focuses on my attempt to return an instance of type `T` thanks to the parametrization `CS[+T <: CS[T]]`. In fact, I used the technique presented in the question [How to use Scala's this typing, abstract types, etc. to implement a Self type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313139/how-to-use-scalas-this-typing-abstract-types-etc-to-implement-a-self-type) by IttayD.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: Trait `CS` implements a Self type to make it possible to return the right type in methods of trait `CS` for an instance of a class that is a specialization of a class mixin trait `CS`. This is exactly the subject discussed in the question previously mentioned. If you take a closer look at the solution proposed by IttayD, you realise that each class `B` specializing a class A mixin trait CS will also mixin trait `CS[B]`. Consequently, the use of existential type is not necessary.

Comment: So does this technique work for you? Do you need to specify the type explicitly like in the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, I just had to specify explicitly the type.

Comment: Well, my entire premise was that you don't want to do this. Hence the existential types. Obviously explicit type annotations will also work.