# Why does implicit type conversion from Int to UInt not work?

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm trying to learn chisel3, and I also try to be able to use implicit type conversion from Int to UInt in  specific case.

Following is my code.

```
package VecTest

import chisel3._
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object VecTestMain extends App {
  Driver.execute(args, () => new VecTest)
}


object VecTest {
  implicit def int2UInt(x: Int) = new fromtIntToLiteral(x).U
}

class VecTest extends Module {
  import VecTest._

  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    val in  = Input(UInt(1.W))
    val out = Output(UInt(8.W))
  })

  val v = VecInit(0x20, 0x30)

  io.out := v(io.in)
}
```

I expected scala compiler will try to convert two values in VecInit from Int to UInt, but compiler reports error like below.

```
[error] /src/directory/this/code/VecTest/VecTest.scala:23:11: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to macro method apply's type parameter bounds [T <: chisel3.core.Data]
[error]   val v = VecInit(0x20, 0x30)
[error]           ^
[error] /src/directory/this/code/VecTest/VecTest.scala:23:19: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(32)
[error]  required: T
[error]   val v = VecInit(0x20, 0x30)
[error]                   ^
[error] /src/directory/this/code/VecTest/VecTest.scala:23:25: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(48)
[error]  required: T
[error]   val v = VecInit(0x20, 0x30)
[error]                         ^
[error] three errors found
```

First, I thougth compiler can not get `int2UInt`(implicit type converter function in `object VecTest`) because of out of scope. However, when I fixed the code like below, it will work.

`val v = VecInit(int2UInt(0x20), int2UInt(0x30))`

I also make a hypotheses that chisel3 already has a implicit type converter like my converter, but that is probably not correct.

Where is my misstakes?

Comment: Did you try specify output type in `implicit def int2UInt(x: Int): ??? = new fromtIntToLiteral(x).U`?

Comment: I tried `implicit def int2UInt(x: Int): UInt = new fromtIntToLiteral(x).U`. However, result wasn't changed.

Comment: and did you try to specify `VecInit[UInt](0x20, 0x30)` ?

Comment: I tried your second solution, and scala compiler works as hoped. Thanks for your advise! My first code is not enough hints for compiler, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest answer is the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278937).
In short, because VecInit is parameterized with [T <: Data] the entire space of T is not searched to see what Implicit conversions might return a T.

You can manually force the proper implicit like this

```
val v = VecInit[UInt](0x20, 0x30)
```

I would like to point out that earlier versions of chisel allowed Int parameters on VecInit and its allies. Our experience was that requiring specific Hardware Types was less error prone and easier to read.  Adding .U to the numbers is fairly low boilerplate overhead.

```
val v = VecInit(0x20.U, 0x30.U)
```