# Trait allowing subtype in method signature

Tags: scala, generics, types

How do I enforce subtype in a method defined in the inherited trait? What do I place in the ??? below

```
trait Organism {
 def reproduce(org:???):Bool
}

class Amoeba extends Organism {
  def reproduce(org:Amoeba) = {// so cute..}

}
class Dinosaur extends Organism {
 def reproduce(org:Dinosaur) = { // so scary} 
}
```

My Client Code will be something like:

```
object BoozeParty {
 def gonuts() = {
    val (maleOrganism:Organism,femaleOrganism:Organism) = getOrganisms()

    maleOrganism.reproduce(femaleOrganism)

 }
}
```

The above code should work irrespective of me sending dinosaurs or amoebas via the method getOrganisms() as it returns a tuple of (Organism,Organism)

The two concepts that I want to achieve are:

- Amoeba knows how to mate with Amoeba and Dinosaur knows how to mate
  with Dinosaur. So let them figure out the intricate details.
- A dinosaur should not be passed to an amoeba. Only an amoeba to an amoeba

Comment: i am pretty sure you can define a trait that has a reference to itself, so it would be trait Org{ def rep(org:Org)}

Comment: but that may allow me to rep Amoeba with Dinosaur? which I don't want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's common to use something called F-bounded polymorphism (see [Scala School](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded)).

```
trait Organism[Self <: Organism[Self]] { self: Self =>
  def reproduceWith(org:Self):Boolean
}

class Amoeba extends Organism[Amoeba] {
  def reproduceWith(org:Amoeba) = ???
}

class Dinosaur extends Organism[Dinosaur] {
  def reproduceWith(org:Dinosaur) = ???
}

class Monster extends Dinosaur
```

`Organism[X]` where `X` states that it must be an `Organism[X]`. This means that only an `X` can be passed in that also extends `Organism[X]`.

To prevent `Dinosaur extends Organism[Amoeba]` I have added a self type `self: Self =>` that tells the compiler this trait should be mixed in with the type that was passed in.

The `mate` function now looks like this:

```
def mate[Species <: Organism[Species]](male:Species, female:Species) = 
  male reproduceWith female
```

Usage is like this:

```
val a1 = new Amoeba
val a2 = new Amoeba

val d1 = new Dinosaur 
val d2 = new Monster 

mate(a1, a2)
mate(d1, d2)
// wont compile
// mate(a1, d1)
```

If you want even more restriction on the types (and with that more complex code) you can take a look at this answer: [Scala: implementing method with return type of concrete instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729996/scala-implementing-method-with-return-type-of-concrete-instance/14910318#14910318)