# F-Bound Polymorphism with Abstract Types instead of Parameter Types?

Tags: scala, generics, types

How do I convert the following F-Bound Polymorphism to code using Abstract Types?

```
trait Organism[Self <: Organism[Self]] { self: Self =>
  def reproduceWith(org:Self):Boolean
}

class Amoeba extends Organism[Amoeba] {
  def reproduceWith(org:Amoeba) = //..code
}
```

Comment: where do you want to use an abstract type? Self is abstract in Organism.

Comment: BTW, F-Bound polymorphism is imo 90% of the time a code smell, it's really rare that you actually really have to use this pattern.

Comment: @AloisCochard: My use case is something similar to the question I asked here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068398/trait-allowing-subtype-in-method-signature. I would be very interested in knowing your design. I can give more use cases if required

Comment: Same question [as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225582/f-bounded-quantification-through-type-member-instead-of-type-parameter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. Here is one way that I like, that is similar to "parameterized modules"
OCaml or Agda.

When you define your `Organism` type, you split it into an abstract type `Organism` and a trait `OrganismOps`. Then you wrap both of these in a trait:

```
trait OrganismSystem {
    type Organism <: OrganismOps

    trait OrganismOps {
        def reproduceWith(org: Organism): Boolean
    }
}
```

Because they are wrapped in the same trait, `OrganismOps` can see the `Organism` type.

Now if you want to create a concrete instance of these things, you would do this:

```
object MyOrganismSystem extends OrganismSystem {
    case class Organism(species: String) extends OrganismOps {
        def reproduceWith(org: Organism) = species == org.species
    }
}
```

And if you want to define methods that operate generically on organism systems, you would have them take in an `OrganismSystem` as a parameter, or, equivalently, wrap them in a class that takes an `OrganismSystem` as a parameter:

```
class UsesGenericOrganismSystem(system: OrganismSystem) {
    import system._

    def allCompatible(organisms: Traversable[Organism]): Boolean =
        organisms.toSeq.combinations(2) forall {
            case Seq(o1, o2) => o1.reproduceWith(o2)
        }
}
```