# How can I check that method parameters have the same type as the methods this?

Tags: scala

I have a use-case where I want to do something like

```
trait Foo {
  def bar[T](x: T)(implicit ev: x.type =:= this.type) = {}
}
```

so, that a call to bar only compiles, when the parameter x has the same type as the class where the method is called upon.

It's clear, that the this.type doesn't help in this case, because each instance has a different this.type, this should only illustrate the goal.

The complete problem looks like this:

```
trait Foo {
  def bar[B <: Foo](o: B) = {} // with some check added
}

abstract class Abstract extends Foo

class Concrete1 extends Abstract

class Concrete2 extends Abstract 

case class Wrapped(a: Abstract)

val c1a = new Concrete1
val c1b = new Concrete1
val c2 = new Concrete2
val ts1 = new Wrapped(new Concrete1)

c1a.bar(c1b) // should compile
ts1.a.bar(c1b) // should also compile
c2.bar(c1b)  // should not compile
```

Using abstract types I found a solution that compiles c1a.bar(c1b) and doesn't compile c2.bar(c1b) as intended, but also doesn't compile ts1.a.bar(c1b). I checked also other ideas like the approach described in update2 of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313139/how-to-use-scalas-this-typing-abstract-types-etc-to-implement-a-self-type), but here the covariance of Self doesn't allow to define bar.

Exist there a solution that I didn't see? Without making Abstract a generic type (which I want to avoid).

Thanks

Comment: On your example `ts1` is of type `Wrapped` which has nothing to do with `Abstract`. It only happens to have a field with type `Abstract`, but its no part of its hierarchy in any way, it won't even have a `bar` method.

Comment: Yep, sorry, this was a mistake. Of course I mean ts1.a.bar, not ts1.bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way of doing something like this (without introducing type parameters) is by introducing an `abstract type`. `Foo` needs to know the type in it's `bar` method:

```
trait Foo {
  type Self
  def bar[T <: Self](o: T) = {} // with some check added
}

abstract class Abstract extends Foo {
  type Self = Abstract
}

class Concrete1 extends Abstract {
  type Self = Concrete1
}

class Concrete2 extends Abstract {
  type Self = Concrete2
}
```

The problem here is that you can easily make a typeo on the `Self` type. That can be solved by adding a new trait called `StrictSelf` (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729996/scala-implementing-method-with-return-type-of-concrete-instance/14910318)):

```
trait StrictSelf[T <: StrictSelf[T]] { self: T =>
  type Self >: self.type <: T
}
```

The complete code would then look like this:

```
trait Foo { self:StrictSelf[_] =>
  def bar[T <: Self](o: T) = {}
}

abstract class Abstract extends Foo { self:StrictSelf[_] => }

class Concrete1 extends Abstract with StrictSelf[Concrete1] {
  type Self = Concrete1
}

class Concrete2 extends Abstract with StrictSelf[Concrete2] {
  type Self = Concrete2
}

case class Wrapped[T <: Abstract with StrictSelf[T]](a: T)
```

In your case you could also use the following (more simple) variant:

```
trait SelfType[T <: SelfType[T]] { self:T =>
  type Self >: T
}

trait Foo { self:SelfType[_] =>
  def bar(o: Self) = {}
}

abstract class Abstract extends Foo {self: SelfType[_] => }

class Concrete1 extends Abstract with SelfType[Concrete1]

class Concrete2 extends Abstract with SelfType[Concrete2]

case class Wrapped[T <: Abstract](a: T)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could parameterize your trait like this:

```
trait Foo[T]{
  def bar(t:T) = {}
}
```

and then class extending the trait would give their own type when extending:

```
abstract class Abstract[T] extends Foo[T]

class Concrete1 extends Abstract[Concrete1]
class Concrete2 extends Abstract[Concrete2]
case class Wrapped[T](a:Abstract[T])
```

This would solve your problem at the expense of having to define the type on each class that extends from `Foo`.

Comment: Yep, that is true, but this solution I want to avoid (which I tried to express with the "Without making Abstract a generic type" part at the end). As already can be seen, this need also a changed Wrapper, which is only a placeholder in the example for the classes which has an member of type Abstract. And this is then only the start how it's spread into the code.

Answer (score 0):

EECOLORs answer works great and is nearer to the Question then the alternative Solution I found myself in the meantime. But this alternative solution fits very well my usecase, so maybe it could be also interessting for others who are stumpling later on this Question.

I moved bar to a new Object:

```
object Bar {
  def bar[A <: Foo, B <: Foo](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B) = {}
}
```

and also made the Wrapper class generic:

```
case class Wrapped[T <: Abstract](a: T)
```

Of course you must write now `Bar.bar(c1a, c1b)` instead of `c1a.bar(c1b)`. In my use case Bar.bar translates to `Distance.euclidean(c1a, c1b)`, so this is fine.