# Preserving type after modification of elements of a shapeless HMap

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to use `HList` to model a collection of objects sharing the same parent. I would like to be able to:

- access elements of the collection using an index
- transform certain elements of the collection using methods defined on the parent

I was able to solve the first point above (in method `withIndex` below). However, IntelliJ IDEA shows a highlighting error with the message `Expression of type at.Out doesn't conform to expected type T`. Is there an implicit that I could add in order to get rid of this?

For the second point (method `modify` below), I get a compilation error

```
Error:(31, 13) type mismatch;
 found   : result.type (with underlying type Value)
 required: T
        result
```

Is there an implicit that I could add in order to get rid of the `asInstanceOf` casting, such that I can apply the `modify` method? And besides, I would like to be able to get the same type of object even after applying the `modify` method. As you can see the `Additive` and `Multiplicative` implement the `modify` method properly. I'm struggling to find a way to provide the evidence that this is really the case ...

This the code referenced above:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.At

sealed trait Value {

    val value: Double

    def modify(newValue: Double): Value
}

case class Additive(value: Double) extends Value {

    def modify(newValue: Double): Additive = this.copy(value = value + newValue)
}

case class Multiplicative(value: Double) extends Value {

    def modify(newValue: Double): Multiplicative = this.copy(value = value * newValue)
}

case class Collection[L <: HList](values: L)
                             (implicit
                              val ev: LUBConstraint[L, Value]) {

    def withIndex[T <: Value](index: Nat)(implicit at: At.Aux[L, index.N, T]): T = values(index)

    def modify[T <: Value](index: Nat, newValue: Double)(implicit at: At.Aux[L, index.N, T]): T = {
        val value = values(index)
        val result = value.asInstanceOf[T].modify(newValue)

        result
    }
}

object App {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val val1 = Additive(1.0)
        val val2 = Additive(2.0)

        val val3 = Multiplicative(3.0)

        val coll = Collection(val1 :: val2 :: val3 :: HNil)

        val copyVal1: Additive = coll.withIndex(0)
        val copyVal2: Additive = coll.withIndex(1)
        val copyVal3: Multiplicative = coll.withIndex(2)

        coll.modify(0, 1.0)
        coll.modify(1, 2.0)
        coll.modify(2, 3.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first point, maybe it's a quirk in IntelliJ Idea? Regarding the second point, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313139/how-to-use-scalas-this-typing-abstract-types-etc-to-implement-a-self-type

Comment: Following the suggestion of @devkat, I added a type in the trait `Value`: `type Self <: Value` and then change the signature of `modify` method in `Collection` to `def modify[T <: Value, TT <: Value](index: Nat, newValue: Double)(implicit at: At.Aux[L, index.N, T], ev: T#Self =:= TT): TT`. After these changes the code compiles. However, I'm pretty sure there should be a way to provide implicitly evidence that result of `at` is of type `T` and avoid casting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the reference provided by @devkat, I managed to refine the code to solve the two issues stated in the question. In my real-work application, the class structure is more nested so I had to use F-bounded polymorphism and self-type to achieve the desired results. For completeness, here is the final version of my code.

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.At

sealed trait Value[+V <: Value[V]] {
    this: V =>

    val value: Double

    def modify(newValue: Double): V

    def chainModify(newValues: List[Double]): V = {
        newValues.foldLeft(this)((obj, v) => obj.modify(v))
    }
}

case class Additive(value: Double) extends Value[Additive] {

    def modify(newValue: Double) = this.copy(value = value + newValue)
}

case class Multiplicative(value: Double) extends Value[Multiplicative] {

    def modify(newValue: Double) = this.copy(value = value * newValue)
}

trait NonCommutative extends Value[NonCommutative] {

}

case class Divisive(value: Double) extends NonCommutative with Value[Divisive] {

    def modify(newValue: Double) = this.copy(value = value / newValue)
}

case class Collection[L <: HList](values: L)
                                 (implicit val ev: LUBConstraint[L, Value[_]]) {

    def withIndex[T <: Value[T]](index: Nat)(implicit at: At.Aux[L, index.N, T]): T = values(index)

    def modify[T <: Value[T]](index: Nat, newValue: Double)(implicit at: At.Aux[L, index.N, T]): T = {
        val value = values(index)
        val result = value.modify(newValue)

        result
    }
}

object App {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val val1 = Additive(1.0)
        val val2 = Additive(2.0)

        val val3 = Multiplicative(3.0)

        val val4 = Divisive(4.0)

        val coll = Collection(val1 :: val2 :: val3 :: val4 :: HNil)

        val copyVal1: Additive = coll.withIndex(0)
        val copyVal2: Additive = coll.withIndex(1)
        val copyVal3: Multiplicative = coll.withIndex(2)
        val copyVal4: Divisive = coll.withIndex(3)

        println(copyVal3.chainModify(1.0 :: 2.0 :: 3.0 :: Nil))

        println(coll.modify(0, 1.0))
        println(coll.modify(1, 2.0))
        println(coll.modify(2, 3.0))
        println(coll.modify(3, 4.0))
    }
}
```