# Scala return self type in parametrized function

Tags: scala, types

I wanted to post a follow-up to the answer to [How to use Scala's this typing, abstract types, etc. to implement a Self type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313139/how-to-use-scalas-this-typing-abstract-types-etc-to-implement-a-self-type)
but I cannot since I don't have enough reputation to post a follow-up.

I have an abstract type and want to return an instance of the concrete type in a function in order to be able to use this function in another parametrized function:

```
trait Abstract {
  def test(): <concrete type>
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
  override def test(): Concrete = new Concrete
}

def fun[C <: Abstract](c: C): C = c.test()
```

The first solution with `this.type` does not work for me since I want to be able to return a new instance of a `Concrete` in the `test()`method.

So I tried the second solution:

```
trait Abstract {
  type Self <: Abstract
  def test(): Self
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
  override type Self = Concrete
  override def test(): Concrete = new Concrete
}
```

But it would not compile:

```
def fun[C <: Abstract](c: C): C = c.test()

> [error] type mismatch;
> [error] found   : c.Self
> [error] required: C
```

Which is pretty logical since I could have overridden `Self` type with anything in another concrete implementation of `Abstract`.

What I would like to avoid is:

```
trait Abstract2[C] {
  def test(): C
}

class Concrete2 extends Abstract2[Concrete2] {
  override def test(): Concrete2 = new Concrete2
}

def fun2[C <: Abstract2[C]](c: C): C = c.test()
```

because it is harder for clients to use. Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired signature is wrong, because it would allow following code:

```
val c1: Concrete = new Concrete
val c2: c1.type = fun[c1.type](c1)
```

but the value returned by `fun(c1)` isn't `c1` and so doesn't have type `c1.type`.

But you can change it to `def fun[C <: Abstract](c: C): c.Self = c.test()`. If `C` is `Abstract`, then the compiler knows `c.Self` is a subtype of `Abstract` and the return value can be used anywhere your desired signature's return value can be used. If `C` is `Concrete`, then `c.Self` is `Concrete`. If `C` is `c1.type` in the example above, then the type of `c2` is still `Concrete`.